# How to read data from serial port(COM3) with lua 5.1 or C++

Tags: c++, lua, serial-port, port

I have program written i C++ with lua 5.1 support (otclient)
I trying read COM3 with lua5.1. I tried luaserial in dll format but i can load this dll.
Maybe be esier to read COM3 with c++?
I just want to read raw data from COM3
i decided firty try lua but if easier way will be c++ i try c++

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (and Linux) serial ports are just files that "exist" in the filesystem, and you can read and write to them like you would any other file.

If you want to do this in Lua you can do it by using the io library if you have it loaded ([docs here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.open)).

You can also do this in C++ on Windows using the [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class, or writing to file like above if you want.